# Adding static route in ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-manager, ifconfig

I want to add static route in Ubuntu `eth1` interface. `eth1` interface is up and running. I could add static route using `route add` command and it works. But it was not persistent after reboots.

So I decided to add entry in `/etc/network/interfaces`. But I found only entry for loopback interface in this file. `eth1` was not found. If I simply add the command in that file it doesn't work. Please help me in this.

Comment: @George What you are saying is applicable for iptable commands. But I am not adding iptable command. My command is like this     " route add  -net 172.16.59.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.74.135 dev eth1"                                                      
￼

Comment: Let me check that...

Comment: Please add that command `/sbin/route
 route add -net 172.16.59.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.74.135 dev eth1`  to the `/etc/rc.local` file to persist between reboot...

Comment: Please run `sudo lshw | grep eth` to get the name of your device...

Comment: This one did not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are many recommended solutions. Most of those weren't working for me.

There was one solution which worked. Here are the steps:

1. You can install `ifupdown-extra` in Ubuntu.

   ```
   sudo apt install ifupdown-extra
   ```
2. Then go to `/etc/network/network-routes`. Here we can add our static route.

   The syntax is explained in `network-routes` file itself. Route added like this will persist on reboots.

Comment: I did not find this would work on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 (bionic). Instead, the network wired connection panel let me add routes in the IPv4 tab. Presumably this would work for IPv6 as well.